# Two float[] outputs in one kernel pass (Sobel -> Magnitude and Direction)

Tags: allocation, renderscript

I wrote the following rs code in order to calculate the magnitude and the direction within the same kernel as the sobel gradients.

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.xxx)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

rs_allocation bmpAllocIn, direction;
int32_t width;
int32_t height;

// Sobel, Magnitude und Direction
float __attribute__((kernel)) sobel_XY(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
float sobX=0, sobY=0, magn=0;

// leave a border of 1 pixel
if (x>0 && y>0 && x<(width-1) && y<(height-1)){
    uchar4 c11=rsGetElementAt_uchar4(bmpAllocIn, x-1, y-1); uchar4   c12=rsGetElementAt_uchar4(bmpAllocIn, x-1, y);uchar4 c13=rsGetElementAt_uchar4(bmpAllocIn, x-1, y+1);
    uchar4 c21=rsGetElementAt_uchar4(bmpAllocIn, x, y-1);uchar4 c23=rsGetElementAt_uchar4(bmpAllocIn, x, y+1);
    uchar4 c31=rsGetElementAt_uchar4(bmpAllocIn, x+1, y-1);uchar4 c32=rsGetElementAt_uchar4(bmpAllocIn, x+1, y);uchar4 c33=rsGetElementAt_uchar4(bmpAllocIn, x+1, y+1);

    sobX= (float) c11.r-c31.r + 2*(c12.r-c32.r) + c13.r-c33.r;
    sobY= (float) c11.r-c13.r + 2*(c21.r-c23.r) + c31.r-c33.r;

    float d = atan2(sobY, sobX);
    rsSetElementAt_float(direction, d, x, y);
    magn= hypot(sobX, sobY);
}
else{
    magn=0;
    rsSetElementAt_float(direction, 0, x, y);
}
 return magn;
}
```

And the Java part:

```
float[] gm = new float[width*height]; // gradient magnitude
float[] gd = new float[width*height]; // gradient direction
        ScriptC_sobel script;
        script=new ScriptC_sobel(rs);
        script.set_bmpAllocIn(Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bmpGray));

        // dirAllocation: reference to the global variable "direction" in rs script. This
        // dirAllocation is actually the second output of the kernel. It will be "filled" by
        // the rsSetElementAt_float() method that include a reference to the current
        // element (x,y) during the passage of the kernel.
        Type.Builder TypeDir = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.F32(rs));
        TypeDir.setX(width).setY(height);
        Allocation dirAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, TypeDir.create());
        script.set_direction(dirAllocation);

        // outAllocation: the kernel will slide along this global float Variable, which is
        // "formally" the output (in principle the roles of the outAllocation (magnitude) and the
        // second global variable direction (dirAllocation)could have been switched, the kernel
        // just needs at least one in- or out-Allocation to "slide" along.)
        Type.Builder TypeOut = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.F32(rs));
        TypeOut.setX(width).setY(height);
        Allocation outAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, TypeOut.create());
        script.forEach_sobel_XY(outAllocation); //start kernel

        // here comes the problem
        outAllocation.copyTo(gm) ;
        dirAllocation.copyTo(gd);
```

In a nutshell: this code works for my older Galaxy Tab2 (API17) but it creates a crash (Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9e6d4000 in tid 6385) with my Galaxy S5 (API 21). The strange thing is that when I use a simpler Kernel that just calculates SobelX or SobelY gradients in the very same way (except the 2nd allocation, here for the direction), it works also on the S5. Thus, the Problem cannot be some compatibility issue. Also, as I said, the kernel itself passes without problems (I can log the Magnitude and direction values) but it struggles with the above .copyTo Statements. As you can see the gm and gd floats have the same dimensions (width*height) as all other allocations used by the kernel. Any idea what the Problem could be? Or is there an alternative, more robust way to do the whole Story?

Comment: Where are width and height computed from? In order for your above algorithm to work, width and height must be *exactly* the width and height of your input bitmap. If they are not, you will most certainly see SIGBUS. Can you also share more log information about the SIGBUS? Is the SIGBUS actually during the copyTo()? You can also try to use the DEBUG context flag (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/RenderScript.ContextType.html). That can help with figuring out where the out of bounds access is coming from.

Comment: Good point about width/height origin. Other than that, I have tested this code on OnePlus One (4.4.4), HTC One M7 (5.0.2) and Nexus 5 (5.1.1), and it runs everywhere with no crashes.

Comment: width and height are calculated just before the above Java code as int width = bmpGray.getWidth(); int height = bmpGray.getHeight();
When I set a Log.e("back in Java ", "kernel finished") just after script.forEach I see this message in logcat and thus conclude that the kernel passed completely. But if I set a log after the Allocation.copyTo Statements this doesn't appear anymore. I need to do some more study (also with regard to DEBUG context) and will post an update. Again: the Problem appears just with my Samsung S5 (5.0), it works with the Tab2.

Comment: Not sure how I missed it before, but you have "width" and "height" variables in Renderscript that you use without initializing them first. This could actually be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Miloslaw, but unfortunately the problem still persists, strange problem. But I strongly believe that the problem is not with the kernel the kernel finshes - I can measure the (crazy!) speed for completion, but it stops at the copyTo Statements.  But I will not give up now, I will have solved that by the end of the week. Still studying the documentation and make my own summary of it.

Comment: Sometimes a problem caused by kernel stomping on invalid memory can manifest itself later. Can you comment out the forEach_sobel_XY line and see if the copyTo() still crashes?

Comment: Indeed, after commenting out the forEach_sobelXY it does not crash anymore. Which proves that there is a Problem within the kernel pass. Need to do more checks on the kernel calculation. The atan2(sobY, sobX) with sobX=0 should not be a Problem according to the documentation. Must be some other constellation that creates the problem.

Comment: @dkSettembrini66 If your "width" and "height" variables in Renderscript code are now set correctly (are they?), the next thing you can do is comment out individual lines that you suspect can cause the crash and see if things change. Shotgun debugging can be effective if underlying principles are not clear.

Comment: The problem was with atan2(), didn't figure out what is was in detail (of course it is always critical to divide by small numbers). I replaced it by my own proxy. Wow, this was hard, but it was worth the effort, just this part increased the speed by 30%. I anyway planned to use my own proxies for atan and hypot, since these are heavy functions when performed a million times.... Thanks for the great support, Miloslaw.

Comment: Follow-up question on this one (there is still a point to earn here ;-)). I want to collect the highest occuring Magnitude value (maxMagn=0; if (magn>MaxMagn){ maxMagn=magn;} during the kernel pass. How can I best do that? Can I set another global variable MaxMagn (as a single float value). And how can I access that from Java?

Comment: You can use the rsAtomicMax() function to do this. Note that this may cause a lot of contention on the various threads, so please check that the performance is ok for your needs. We are putting together a "reduce()" API in AOSP right now, but it won't be available until a future Android release. That would get you a max() extremely efficiently.